# Xcode change the description(header) of the file that was just created

Tags: xcode, header, licensing

When I create a new file in my project in the file header, I find this:

```
//
//  NameFile.swift
//  NameProject
//
//  Created by Name Surname on dd/mm/yy.
//
```

I would like to change it, but in the settings I don't find where to do it.

I would like to change it for all possible future projects.

I would like to achieve such a thing.

```
//
//  NameFile.swift
//  NameProject
//
//
```

Edit:

I would like to try to remove the comment, but I can't find solutions.

Comment: Search StackOverflow for the keyword `IDETemplateMacros.plist`. Also, check out this article: https://oleb.net/blog/2017/07/xcode-9-text-macros/

Comment: OK, I think I've found a way by following a tutorial on yt.

But is there a way to completely get rid of this header comment?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't, but in my current team we just have a one line template that says `// Delete this header` and it works ok.

Comment: This is a real problem.

Answer (score 5):

Say you want to modify (or get rid of) the XCode Header comment.

- First open XCode, Use File > New File... (⌘N) and choose Property List from the file templates.
- Name it file `IDETemplateMacros.plist`
- On the navigator, select the file as right-click `Open as source code`. Xcode will show us the property file as text. Property files are really just XML files.
- Copy paste the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>FILEHEADER</key>
    <string>Created for ___PROJECTNAME___ in ___YEAR___
// Using Swift ___DEFAULTTOOLCHAINSWIFTVERSION___</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

On the root dict we have added an entry with key FILEHEADER and a two-lines string as a value:

```
Created for ___PROJECTNAME___ in ___YEAR___
// Using Swift ___DEFAULTTOOLCHAINSWIFTVERSION___
```

Save the file IDETemplateMacros.plist on the folder:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/
```

That's it, now when creating a new project called MyProject the header will be:

```
//Created for MyProject in 2022
// Using Swift 5.0
```

**Note1**. There is a list of macros on https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/9.0/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/dev7fe737ce0

**Note 2**. As an example you can write:

```
 Created ___DATE___
// ___COPYRIGHT___
```

Note that there is a leading space but you do not include the // for the comment on the first line.

**Note 3**. For a more list of options see:
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/changing-xcode-header-comment/

Answer (score 1):

From https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711305?answerId=722311022#722311022

Add `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/IDETemplateMacros.plist` with an empty `FILEHEADER` entry to generate an empty comment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>FILEHEADER</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Xcode help:

- Customize text macros:
  https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/?localePath=en.lproj#/dev91a7a31fc
- Text macros reference:
  https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/dev7fe737ce0

If you really want to remove that empty comment line then you will need to start adding custom file templates. eg for a `No Comment Swift File` template create the following:

- `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/MultiPlatform/Source/No Comment Swift File.xctemplate/___FILEBASENAME___.swift` with `import Foundation`
  followed by an empty line
- `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/MultiPlatform/Source/No Comment Swift File.xctemplate/TemplateInfo.plist` with something like

`TemplateInfo.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>SupportsSwiftPackage</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Kind</key>
    <string>Xcode.IDEFoundation.TextSubstitutionFileTemplateKind</string>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>A no comment Swift file.</string>
    <key>Summary</key>
    <string>A no comment Swift file</string>
    <key>SortOrder</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>Image</key>
    <dict>
        <key>FileTypeIcon</key>
        <string>swift</string>
    </dict>
    <key>AllowedTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>public.swift-source</string>
    </array>
    <key>Platforms</key>
    <array/>
    <key>DefaultCompletionName</key>
    <string>File</string>
    <key>MainTemplateFile</key>
    <string>___FILEBASENAME___.swift</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The default empty Swift File template in the Xcode 14 beta is: `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/MultiPlatform/Source/Swift File.xctemplate/` (do not edit this directly).